# No module named 'virtualenv.seed.via_app_data'

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, virtualenv

Estiy intentado crear un entorno virtual de python en Ubuntu, este el mensaje que muesta cuando se ejecuta este comando:

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3.6 ./<nombre>:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenv.seed.via_app_data'
```

Comment: Bienvenidx a la comunidad de Stackoverflow. Por favor lee o visita de nuevo el [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Recuerda que debes anteponer un título que describa bien el problema que tienes, así como resumir tu pregunta en los primeros párrafos explicando concretamente tu pregunta. Esto y otras cosas más que encontrarás en el link que te cité, aumentará tus posibilidades de recibir ayuda por parte de la comunidad.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que puedes tener un `virtualenv` distinto en tu sistema del que tienes para Python.

La forma más fácil de crear un nuevo entorno sin problemas, es llamar directamente al módulo desde Python, lo puedes hacer con el siguiente comando:

```
python3 -m venv nombre_entorno
```

Utilizando la opción `-m` es como conseguimos llamar al paquete usando la versión de Python.